# What is the expected relation of self-defense to real-life?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the [self-defense](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-defense), [which a bit hazy in its definition](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/407/should-the-self-defense-tag-be-burninated). What is the relation of [real-life](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-life) to self-defense? Is there any self-defense situation that is not also real-life?

Comment: Are you comparing stuff from like movies or self defense scenarios that you may have learned?

Comment: @YesTeacher This question is about the current usage of tags on the main site. You can how the tags are being used there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [real-life](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-life) should be burninated. Everything here is real life unless otherwise specified (i.e. it is a question about a movie or storybook technique).