# Real life tag burnination

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Can we burninate the [real-life](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-life) tag?  It serves no usefulness here since fictional martial arts are off topic. The [real-life](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-life) tagged [questions](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-life?sort=newest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burninating (?) [real-life](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-life) was the only real thought from [What is the expected relation of self-defense to real-life?](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/what-is-the-expected-relation-of-self-defense-to-real-life)

Comment: And yet, the tag lingers like a bad smell... 

Comment: Note that I would delete it, if I knew how to do it. Although, I would much rather there was a consensus from the community before doing so.

Comment: @Sardathrion the questions just need to be re-tagged. Once the tag has been eliminated from any questions then it should automatically age away. We could look to black list it if it ever comes back. Generally we avoid burnination unless there is either a lot of questions to remove it from - burninating would leave some of those questions without a tag at all, so when there's small numbers it's best to do it manually.

Comment: @slugster Shall I do that then?

Comment: @Sardathrion I've edited the tag out of questions, it will die in about 24 hours or so.

Comment: @slugster: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I'm with that. The self-defense tag pretty much covers everything people are really asking about when they use the term "real life".